# bcrypt rebuild stuck in dind image build

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, bcrypt, docker-in-docker

As per the title, trying to build an image via dind worker (on jenkins running on kubernetes) and the `RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source` command appears to get "stuck"; no additional logs to give more detail.

Remains stuck indefinitely (I've let it 'try' for over 6 hours)

Image build Logs:

```
10:58:57  Step 16/22 : RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
10:58:57   ---> Running in 0342d5df1122
10:59:00  
10:59:00  > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /usr/src/app/node_modules/bcrypt
10:59:00  > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

I've tried changing dind image versions, adding/removing dockerfile dependencies, and some others.

**NOTE** this builds fine on my local with docker engine v20.10.12!

Any help is appreciated!

---

Additional info and running versions:

**dind image**: `17.12.1-dind` (but I've also tried 18.x.x-dind, 19.x.x-dind, and 20.x.x-dind)

**jenkins version**: `2.330`

**bcrypt version**: `5.0.1`

**npm image version**: `12.22.9-alpine`

**Dockerfile** (with some redactions):

```
FROM node:12.22.9-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .builds-deps bash git build-base python3 make g++ openssh

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source  # <-- this is where it fails

RUN apk del make g++ python3 openssh

COPY src /usr/src/app/src

RUN adduser -S -u 10001 -g nodejs nodejs && chmod +x /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

(Note that I've added some of these dependencies in my debugging; I don't actually need them)

---

Additionally, this works fine with bcrypt version `2.0.1` and node `10.16.3-alpine` image but I wanted to upgrade node version and therefore had to upgrade bcrypt

Thanks!

***Edit:*** Updated some words